# JAVA - How to get text after a particular character?

Tags: java, string

I have a String `Chocolate:30:2` in a variable and I want to extract the number after the second colon i.e. `2`. So, How can I extract that number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

```
String s = "Chocolate:30:2";
String number = s.split(":")[2];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the second colon is actually the last colon, you can use:

```
String after = str.substring(1 + str.lastIndexOf(':'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String lastIndexOf method.

```
String result = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(':') + 1);
```